# Exercise of VII 5.2 Massey's Algebraic Topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is a question about an exercise in William Massey’s A Basic Course in Algebraic Topology. Chapter VII, Question 5.2.

Let $X_i$ be the pathwise-connected components of $X$, show that $H_n(X,A)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of all the groups $H_n(X_i,A \cap X_i)$.

I can only say this seems obvious, but how to prove this logically.

Comment: Can you write down an isomorphism from direct sum of cocycles for $(X_i, A \cap X_i)$ to cocycles of $(X,A)$? Does this map restrict to an isomorphism on coboundary? If so, the quotient is then isomorphic.

Comment: Write $X=\bigsqcup X_i$ and study isomorphism $H_*(X)=H_*(\bigsqcup X_i)\cong \bigoplus H_*(X_i)$. What maps induce it? Now just insert this into the long exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)=(\bigsqcup X_i,A)$.

Comment: Oh I get it, I seemed to be not quite familiar with these basic things, lol.